# getting error from going to one page to another in Nativescript-vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript, vue-native

actually I m making a shopping app in which there is a situation like suppose(we have 3 pages one is Home , Second one is Single-Product, and third one is Size-Chart) so when I am in home page when I select the product I redirect to the Single-Product page and then inside it their is the button call SHOW SIZE CHART when I click on it should show me the Size-Char page but I got the error like

```
Vue warn]: Error in directive view inserted hook: "Error: View already has a parent. View: ActionBar(336) Parent: Page(335)"
JS: 
JS: found in
JS: 
JS: ---> <ActionBar>
JS:        <Page>
JS:          <Anonymous>
JS:            <NavigationEntry>
JS: [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "Error: View already has a parent. View: ActionBar(336) Parent: Page(335)"
```

I am using the same bellow code to redirect from Home Page To Single-Product page but it I m using the same code in Single_Product page and transferring to the Size-Chart page its not working

The code in **Home Page** to redirect

```
methods:{
            sendToSingleProduct(component,productId){
                this.$navigateTo(component, {
                    props: {
                        ProductId: productId
                    },
                    clearHistory: false
                });
            }
}
```

The code I am using in the **Single-Product** Page which din't work

```
methods:{
            sendToSizeChart(component){
                this.$navigateTo(component, {
                    props: {
                        ProductId: this.productId
                    },
                    clearHistory: false
                });
            }
}
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Can you share a Playground example where the issue can be reproduced. Moreover NavigationEntry in your code is not a valid view.